# how to stop termination of script execution

Tags: vbscript

I am executing one Vbscript with login scripts. is there any way we can stop the user to kill from the taskmanager?
or any way if the user kills it should start the script execution automatically with any code added into the existing code?

Comment: You don't want to prevent users from being able to kill processes running in their context. If your logon scripts are running too long chances are you're doing something wrong on your side (script(s) too large, using scripts where you should be using GPOs or GPPs, insufficient system resources, ...). Please take a step back and describe the underlying problem instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar.......            Coming to the background of the problem      I have the task of monitoring the few processes for every user logged on machine. based on the idle time of the process I would like to kill the process. for that I wrote the vbscript code which is running continuously when the user logged in. I would like to run the script continuously as long as user logged in. I do not want the user to kill from task manager.

Comment: You should be running that code in a separate user context (e.g. as a scheduled task launched on system startup). That way regular users won't be able to kill the process (b/c it belongs to a different user). If your users have admin privileges: there's nothing you can do anyway w/o revoking their admin privileges. You cannot protect a system from its administrator.

Comment: I'm not a professional domain admin... but I'm not entirely sure one should just kill any application on Windows based on idle time. Maybe log out users if their workstation has been locked for more than x hours instead?